# Read the Target of a Shortcut using Go

Tags: go, lnk

I'm trying to read the **target** file/directory of a shortcut (.lnk) file using Go.

I already have a loop for all the files in a directory and I can successfully identify if it is a dir with `IsDir()` or if it is a file `IsRegular()`. Now I need a way to read if it is a link and, if it is a `.lnk`, the path of it so I can print it.

I couldn't find any way of doing this and I've been searching on SO but nothing comes up. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You need to read the [lnk binary format as defined by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd891253.aspx)

In Go, its structure would translate to (as used in the [`exponential-decay/shortcuts`](https://github.com/exponential-decay/shortcuts/blob/ff88771677a5e831482e1d74d023864dfe48857f/structs.go#L14-L34))

```
//structs that make up the shortcut specification [76 bytes] 
type ShellLinkHeader struct {
   HeaderSize  [4]byte           //HeaderSize
   ClassID     [16]byte          //LinkCLSID
   LinkFlags   uint32            //LinkFlags      [4]byte
   FileAttr    uint32            //FileAttributes [4]byte
   Creation    [8]byte           //CreationTime
   Access      [8]byte           //AccessTime
   Write       [8]byte           //WriteTime
   FileSz      [4]byte           //FileSize
   IconIndex   [4]byte           //IconIndex
   ShowCmd     [4]byte           //ShowCommand

   //[2]byte HotKey values for shortcut shortcuts
   HotKeyLow   byte              //HotKeyLow
   HotKeyHigh  byte              //HotKeyHigh

   Reserved1   [2]byte           //Reserved1
   Reserved2   [4]byte           //Reserved2
   Reserved3   [4]byte           //Reserved3
}
```

That project should give you an idea to how to decode the shortcut target.

Comment: Does [os.Readlink(path)](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Readlink) not work on Windows?

Comment: @jrefior for symlink (`mklink` or maybe junction: `mklink /J`), as seen in https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15978. Not for "shortcut" (`lnk`)

Comment: @VonC can you write a little example on how to get that info? I'm very lost with this one :(

Comment: @CoppolaEmilio I will, tomorrow (a bit late here at the moment)

Comment: @VonC Sorry to pest you, but can you help me now? I want to accept the answer :)

Comment: @CoppolaEmilio I didn't get far: you can clone the repo and go build it: it will give you a `shortcut.exe` utility that you can use on your `.lnk` file: `shortcut -file c:\path\to\ashortcut.lnk`. But the destination path isn't directly detected. I !suspect it needs to be interpreted and reassembled, following the Microsoft spec.

Comment: @CoppolaEmilio In short, it helps you decoding the structure of a .lnk file, but a bit more work is required in order to retrieve the actual destination path.